# Can you spot the liar?

Tags: code-golf

It's the end of the year, you and your friends have just received your grades and ranks for the GOLF101 class. On a chat group, everyone sends their grade and rank to see who's got the best one.

**Problem:** someone is lying.

Here is an excerpt from the chat:

```
<A> I'm ranked 1 with a grade of 85.
<B> Ranked 3, got 50.
<C> Ranked 1st, prof. gave me 65/100.
<D> Got ranked second with 70/100
```

Obviously here, student C is lying (at least) on their rank; they can't be 1st with a grade of 65 since both A and D got a better grade.

There can also be cases where someone is lying but we can't know who, specifically.

```
Rank | Grade
-------------
  2     71
  1     80
  3     60
  2     70
```

Here, one of the two rank-2 students is lying (since two students can't have the same rank while having different grades) but we can't know which one.

## Challenge

Create a function or program that, when given a sequence of (rank, grade) tuples which contains exactly one *lie*, returns the index of the *lie* in the list or a sentinel value if is impossible to know.

A *lie* is a tuple that, when removed from the list, makes the list valid (i.e. without any conflicting ranks/grades).

A valid list contains **all the possible ranks starting from 1** (or 0 if you use 0-indexing), so the rank sequence `1 2 3` is valid while `2 3 4` is not. The only way to not have every possible rank is when there are equal grades, in which case you can get sequences like `1 2 2` or `1 2 3 3 3`.

Multiple tuples may have the same grade, in which case they will have the same rank, and other tuples' ranks will not be affected. Two tuples having the second-best grade will lead to the sequence `1 2 2 4 ...`.

The input format is not fixed, you may use whatever is easier to parse for your language (a 2D int array, a list of tuples, a list of strings containing space-separated ints). The logic is more important than the parser's implementation details.

The output format is not fixed either. The "index" returned may be 0-based or 1-based, and the sentinel value can be anything that is clearly distinguishable from an index (if you're using 1-based indexing, 0 is a valid sentinel value).

## Test Cases

```
Rank | Grade
-------------
  2     71
  1     80
  3     60
  2     70
```

**Output**: impossible to know

```
Rank | Grade
-------------
  1     85
  3     50
  1     65
  2     70
```

**Output**: third student

```
Rank | Grade
-------------
  1     85
  3     50
  1     65
  2     70
```

**Output**: third student

Additional cases, thanks to @tsh:

- `[(1, 100), (2, 60), (3, 90), (3, 90)]` -> invalid input because we can't remove a single item to get a valid list
- `[(1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 90), (3, 90)]` -> fourth (if we remove the third we get an invalid list with ranks [1, 1, 3])

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte count for each language wins!

**EDIT:** printing multiple values is a valid sentinel as long as you specify it. 0-indexing for ranks is fine too.

Comment: Is it acceptable to output a list of all potential liars, when there are more than 1?

Comment: Can we use 0-indexing for ranks?

Comment: _Multiple tuples may have the same grade, in which case they will have the same rank_: you should probably include some test cases covering this (I think my current solution would fail on them).

Comment: `1 2 2 4` ... wouldn't it be `1 2 2 3`?

Comment: @Jonah, "*other tuples' ranks will not be affected*".

Comment: It just struck me as odd, but I looked it up and apparently it's how it works in the Olympics so my intuition was wrong: "If a pair of athletes or two teams tie for first-place, they each receive a gold medal, no one is awarded silver and the bronze is awarded to the runner-up."

Comment: Is it possible that someone's lie is claim his rank as 5th while there are only 4 people here?

Comment: Suggested testcases: `[(1, 100), (2, 60), (3, 90), (3, 90)] -> 2`, 
`[(1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 90), (2, 90)] -> 1 or 2`, 
`[(1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 90), (3, 90)] -> 3`

Comment: It could be a good question. But bad at test cases. Sadly, all answers currently received are invalid. This won't happen if more test cases are added at the beginning. Also, it makes this question not quite easy one.

Comment: Will there always be at least 2 students?

Comment: Is there a range of grade? For example, if we know the grade may only in range 0~100 inclusive. For input [(1, 95), (2, 100), (3, 90), (4, 80)] we know the 2nd one is lying (he cannot get 100 grade but not 1st rank.) Not the 1st one (only 1 people is lying). But without the knowledge of grade range, it is possible that 1st one is lying while his real grade is 120.

Comment: @tsh You say that all current answers are invalid but without OP confirming, it could be possible that you’re wrong, or that you’ve misunderstood the challenge. I would wait for OP to confirm that specific test cases are what you say they are before commenting on every answer that it fails to work for an example you’ve just come up with

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'm glade to see anyone pointing out any mistake of my testcases (as suggested in previous comment). Please tell me if you found anything incorrect here. I just implemented myself and noticed my submission may be incorrect somehow. And try to verify my idea on all other submissions.

Comment: Suggested testcase: `[(2, 90), (2, 90), (2, 90), (3, 80)] -> 4`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I didn't know all answers are invalid before I test them out one by one. And I would comment each one as long as I find some testcase not working, otherwise I would simply forgot I had tested it. So I believe it is not possible that I ask to OP first then comment anything.

Comment: @tsh that input would be invalid because the ranks are supposed to start from "first" (0 or 1) in the list. I apologize if I weren't clear enough in the specs, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: "`[(1, 100), (2, 60), (3, 90), (3, 90)]` -> invalid input because we can't remove a single item to get a valid list" - but if we remove `(2, 60)` we have a valid list given we know an entry is missing (i.e. `(2, 60)` could be a lie with a reality of `(2, 99)`), so I think we can tell that 2 is lying.

Comment: "`[(1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 90), (3, 90)]` -> fourth (if we remove the third we get an invalid list with ranks `[1, 1, 3]`)" - but if `(2, 90)` was only lying about their rank and not their score then `[1, 1, 3]` *is* a valid result, given we know one person has been removed, (i.e. `(2, 90)` could be a lie with a reality of `(3, 90)`), so I think we can't be sure who of 3 or 4 are lying.

Comment: I'm not sure how you define _conflict_ here. As the question described, *one of these student is lying* and implies others are reporting their real rank and grade. As long as we can construct a valid list of ranking / grade for all student which has exactly one element different from input, we know the different one may be a layer.

Comment: As the question need to return "returns the index of the lie in the list". Does the testcase `[(1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 90), (3, 90)]` -> fourth  means you consider (3, 90) is invalid? As the question described for tie: "Two tuples having the second-best grade will lead to the sequence `1 2 2 4`", rank list `[1, 1, 3]` is valid but `[1, 1, 2]` is invalid. So how `[1, 1, 3]` could be invalid here?

Comment: I've VTC as unclear. I think that the issue might be "A valid list contains all the possible ranks starting from 1" since if our premise is that exactly one student is lying then when attempting to identify that liar (by removing their entry from the input) this does not make sense, it would, I believe, make more sense to additionally define a *valid list of n-1 students* as "Could be missing a single (rank, score) from a valid list". (That would align it with all tsh's comments; and tests can be updated to reflect it).
...cont...

Comment: ...cont... The alternative would be to get rid of the scenario "students, ranks, one liar, etc.." and reword the challenge to something like "Given a list of pairs *<like this>* find the index of the single entry which may be removed such that what remains is a valid list with these given properties *<your properties>*"

Comment: Does the output have to be the index of the liar or can it also be its value like (1,50) ?

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>49 47</sup> 22 bytes

```
[:I.1(-:\:~i.])/@|:\.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5RS4RAFIXf51ccFFaNHGcWtLogLAVBED30qhLizqohDjEjFIV/3Ua3fejhXi7nHr5z3hePByfkhADXECA3McfD6/PjUtATl2FMJc09r6Lk8EMlr5aIvdxz6OEIo4fJ9nrchNV9CP1Z5tJ3bhmGMt/54nvmCY/mq4RiKkoqLhjW5rwgnPC2R1WiYkw1ncYeOVrX4TZ1ZyrclaWQuBFsC7HK2H5sYbvawhvU2NoOvcGoLdRn3djhC@pjqgdYDenRGSox0853XAeSK1w4eCbO3P8OJ4r1ka2Wu7@1JZsuMDBT27oK6rg1QVMbxZZf)

<sup>-14 bytes after reading [xigoi's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219540/15469) of comparing the first index matches to the ranks.</sup>

<sup>Thanks to tsh for a test case showing that we needed "length not equal to 1" rather than "length greater than 1" as the failure criterion.</sup>

Returns 0-based index if exactly one liar is found, and 0 or multiple values otherwise.  Takes "length" by 2 matrix with 0-indexed rank list as left column, score list as right column.

- `1...\.]` For each 1-item outfix (list with item removed), apply the verb...
- `(...)/@|:` Transpose and put the verb in parens between the two rows, so that the rank list is its left arg, and the score list is its right arg.
- `-:\:~i.]` Does the rank list match `-:` the first index of the score list `i.]` within the score list sorted descending `\:~`?  We now have a 0-1 list, where 1 indicates a liar.
- `[:I.` Return the indexes of all ones.

Comment: From the edit into the question: “ printing multiple values is a valid sentinel as long as you specify it.”, so you might be able to save 11 bytes?

Comment: `g 1 90 1 90 1 90 2 80`. `2 80` is lying. `1 90 1 90 2 80` is still invalid as after 2 rank 1, the grade 80 should be rank 3 not 2.

Comment: @tsh For `0 90 0 90 1 80` -- If I remove any single 1 of them, the remaining 2 are valid.  So all 3 could be the liar.  This is what my code says, it returns `0 1 2`.  Am i missing something?  For `0 90 0 90 0 90 1 80`, my code identifies 80 as the liar.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ṙJṖZNÞiⱮḷ⁼ʋ/Ɗ€T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpleD3dOi/I7PC/z0cZ1D3dsf9S451S3/rGuR01rQv4fbgdS//9Hc0VHW5jqGMbqRJsa6BgDKTMIz9xAxyg2VgcobW4IZOlEWxiAxc0gqmDSsQA)

I'm pretty sure it works correctly with the multiple equal grades rule, but I'd appreciate a testcase for that.

Takes a list of [grade, rank]. Returns a 1-indexed list of all possible liars.

### Explanation

```
ṙJṖZNÞiⱮḷ⁼ʋ/Ɗ€T   Main monadic link
ṙ                 Rotate left by
 J                  all of [1..length]
             €    For each rotation
            Ɗ     (
  Ṗ                 Pop (remove the last pair)
   Z                Zip, change to a pair of [grades, ranks]
           /        Reduce by
          ʋ         (
     Þ                Sort the grades by
    N                   their negation
      iⱮḷ             Find the first index of each grade in the reverse-sorted grades
         ⁼            Is this equal to the list of ranks?
          ʋ         )
            Ɗ     )
              T   Find the indices where this is true
```

Comment: Failed: [[1, 100], [2, 60], [3, 90], [3, 90]],

Comment: @tsh That's not a valid test case, there's not a single student you can remove to make the order correct.

Comment: Sorry for wrong order: It should be `[[100,1],[60,2],[90,3],[90,3]]`. Changing `[60, 2]` to `[95, 2]` makes everything valid, I believe. So `[60, 2]` is the student lying.

Comment: @tsh You're not supposed to change a student, but to remove a student.

Comment: Yes, I meant remove [60, 2]. As the question suggests, one of them is lying. Suppose 4 students gets: StudentA 100, StudentB 95, StudentC 90, StudentD 90. And studentA claims (100, 1); StudentB claims (60, 2); StudentC claims (90, 3); StudentD claims (90, 3). We know StudentB is lying.By removing StudentB, the list is [(100, 1), (90, 3), (90, 3)]. And the list does not contains "_any conflicting ranks/grades_". By removing any other items, [90, 3] for example, `[[100,1],[60,2],[90,3]]` still contains conflicting as grade 60 cannot have a higher rank than grade 90.

Comment: @tsh [(100, 1), (90, 3), (90, 3)] does have a conflict. The two students with 90 are in 2nd place, not in 3rd place.